# Computing a predicted value in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a logistic regression model:

```
 proc genmod data=rats;
     model cured/total = dose
           /dist = binomial link=logit;
 run;
```

What I'm wanting to do is compute or derive the dosage based on a given proportion of cured/total. I realize that I can just do algebra based on the model that it gives, but I want to know if there's a way to do it using SAS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using the STORE command inside of GENMOD and then PROC PLM on a new data set.  Briefly:

```
  proc genmod data=remiss descending;
        model remiss = smear blast / dist=binomial;
        store out=logmod;
  run;
  proc plm source=logmod;
        score data=new out=preds pred=pred lclm=lower uclm=upper / ilink;
  run;
```

For details, see [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/kb/33/307.html#ex1)

Now, do do the sort of reverse scoring that you want, just make a data set that goes from some minimal value to some maximal value with small increments

Comment: That's usually the recommendation for scoring, but this is the reverse of scoring. I guess you'd need to pass all values in to see the value you want?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an inverse prediction, which can be obtained using the PROBIT procedure with the INVERSECL option:

```
proc probit data=rats plots=(predpplot ippplot lpredplot)           ;
model cured/total = dose / dist=logistic inversecl;
run;
```

There's a nice example in the documentation:
[SAS/STAT 14.1 PROBIT Example 93.4 An epidemiology study](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_probit_examples04.htm)

Answer (score 0):

(My apologies for the second "answer", I don't have enough points to comment.)

Peter, the advantage to PROBIT is the availability of an interval estimate (fiducial limits) for the inverse prediction.